# All artifacts loaded into the item collection must have the same version. Multiple versions were encountered

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I'm getting this error when I try to access a view in my .edmx:

```
All artifacts loaded into an ItemCollection must have the same version. Multiple versions were encountered.
```

Here's the code that's genereating the error:

```
private IQueryable<daDialogNotes.viewDialogNotesAll> GetAuthorizedList()
    {            
        List<int> authorizedClients = al.GetClientIds();            

        daDialogNotes.NTS2001Entities context = new daDialogNotes.NTS2001Entities();

        IQueryable<daDialogNotes.viewDialogNotesAll> m;
        m = context.viewDialogNotesAlls.Where(x => (authorizedClients.Contains(x.Client_Id))).AsQueryable(); 
        // error in line above          

        return m;
    }
```

Here's an image of my view:

[image]

App.config for the provider:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="NTS2001Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DialogNotes.csdl|res://*/DialogNotes.ssdl|res://*/DialogNotes.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=NTS-UAT;initial catalog=NTS2001;persist security info=True;user id=*******;password=*********;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

I'm running .net 4.5 on everything. The edmx is in another project file and I'm referencing the dll in my application. Googling around I see that people are getting this error when they're upgrading from .net 3.5 to 4.0, but this has always been running on 4.5.

Any ideas?

Comment: When do you get that error? Suppose when running your app. Then please show your config for the provider. Please provide also which database you want to access through EF.

Comment: After reading [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/kencox/archive/2010/07/02/schema-specified-is-not-valid-error-on-upgrading-to-asp-net-4.aspx): I'm starting to wonder if it's an issue with the connection string in the app.config. Specifically this bit: `metadata=res://*/DialogNotes.csdl|res://*/DialogNotes.ssdl|res://*/DialogNotes.msl;`